# Why can't I open multiple sell orders?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities, selling, fidelity

I have bought few EARS shares in Jan (300) and May(500). I am still learning stock market basics. But now, I can not sell 500 shares in profit. Whenever I tried to make trade on Fidelity; I am constantly getting message " Due to an existing, conflicting order for EARS (AURIS MEDICAL HOLDING AG CHF0.40 ), you do not have enough shares available to complete this order. Please review your open orders and make any necessary changes." I am not getting what I did wrong or missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you talk to Fidelity? What did they say?

Comment: "Whenever I tried to trade..."  Maybe the first trade resulted in an open, as yet unfulfilled, order (e.g. you are asking to sell at a price no one wants to pay) and so all subsequent attempts to trade 500 shares are turned down because you have an open order to sell 500 shares, and cannot fulfill another order to sell 500 shares because you have only 300 shares to sell should the first order get executed in the meantime.

Comment: @DJClayworth I talked with them after your reply and it turned out my sell  "limit order" was pending where I was selling 800 stocks. As that order was active; new 500 share sell order couldn't be completed. I had to cancel previous one in order to get sell 500. Thank you :)

Comment: I think this is a good question and should just be edited a bit -- that you can't have two simultaneous sell orders for the same shares sounds on-topic, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the message you report, it sounds like you are trying to sell the same shares twice, you have two open sell orders for the same shares. Either you have accidentally entered two sell orders, or the web site is having a technical problem. I'm not a customer of Fidelity so I can't say what their web site looks like, but there should be some screen that shows your open orders. If looking there doesn't resolve the issue, call customer service.

Comment: Indeed, it was duplicate order that I didn't realized is still active. Webportal could have given me right context than such abstract message, isnt it? Well, I have given feedback to fidelity. or may be it just me learning to interpret messages. Thanks for replying.